# Python paramiko Import failed

Tags: python

i installed python3 by default path. while running python script from redhat machine i am getting below error.

```
yum install python3
pip3 install paramiko
```

```
whereis python
/usr/lib64/python3.6
```

And also installed required paramiko packages as well.

```
[root@devops tmp]# pip3 -V
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

```
pip3 list
bcrypt (3.2.0)
cffi (1.14.3)
cryptography (3.1.1)
paramiko (2.7.2)
pip (9.0.3)
pycparser (2.20)
PyNaCl (1.4.0)
setuptools (39.2.0)
six (1.15.0)
```

when i am executing python script i am following error "import error No module name paramiko"

Comment: And if you do a `pip3 list` ?

Comment: Hi, pip3 list updated above, please help me on this

Comment: are you sure you are running the script with the same python instance that has the paramiko installation?

Comment: That's the next question - no virtual envs? Do you haev a shebang at the top of the script specifying a different python path? How exactly are you running this script?

Comment: also try this: sudo -H pip install paramiko --ignore-installed (https://github.com/FSecureLABS/needle/issues/3)

Comment: I'm running same machine where i installed python and other packages, and i have shebang  specified inside the python file #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: This command will uninstall the package sudo -H pip install paramiko --ignore-installed?

Comment: There's your problem. `/usr/bin/python` does not match the python path you cite above. You've installed your package on a different python installation. I suggest always using virtual environments :)

Comment: what is mean by virtual environment, and aslo i will run the script like this python execute_bash.py 1.2.3.4 -u root -p password -b script.sh